# Generating examples by applying conditions to symbolic expressions

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation

For example,

Given a list of symbolic expressions:

```
ClearAll[a,o,t];
myexpr = 
{
1 - t + 2 a[1] + (2 - t + 2 a[1]) (-1 + t + a[1] + o[1]) + (1 + a[1]) (-1 + t + a[1] + o[1])^2,
-1 + t + a[1] + o[1]
}
```

Given conditions on those symbols:

```
mycond = (1 <= t <= 3 && a[1] == t && o[1] > 3 - 2 t + a[1]) || (t > 3 && a[1] == t && o[1] >= 0)
```

And given "transformation" function `foo`,

How can I "apply" those conditions to the expression and generate examples?

By "apply", I mean:

Every case of conditions separated by `||` is handled on its own.

In every case, for subcondition of form `X == Y`, all `X` get replaced by `Y` (or the other way around) so only one of the two remains in the expressions.

In case of a `>=,>` or `<=,<` subconditions, those set up the relative bounds for symbols, lets call them `boundLow,boundHigh`. If no bound is set, the extreme bounds are used.

The final bounds depend on given extreme bounds `boundMin,boundMax` which restrict bounds `boundLow,boundHigh` by having final bounds for every symbol: `Max[boundLow,boundMin],Min[boundHigh,boundMax]`.

That is, the desired output is in this example: (After `==` substitutions in `myexpr` and `myconds`)

```
{Table[foo[myexpr],{t,Max[1,boundMin],Min[3,boundMax]},{o[1],Max[4-t,boundMin],boundMax}],
Table[foo[myexpr],{t,Max[4,boundMin],boundMax},{o[1],Max[0,boundMin],boundMax}]}
```

Where we have tables of examples generated by applying the `myconds` (which consist of two cases separated by `||` and thus we have two tables) to `myexpr`.

---

In the above example, I manually did the `==` replacements with `/. ->` and manually set the bounds - how can I automate this process of "applying" conditions to expressions to generate examples?

Motivation

The above example is an actual output from an algorithm I'm trying to make that solves a problem I'm trying to solve - in this question, I'm wondering how can I generate examples from such outputs, to analyze them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but this sounds like a case for [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html):

```
FindInstance[#, Variables[myexpr]] & /@ (List @@ mycond)
```

> `{{{t -> 3, a[1] -> 3, o[1] -> 5}}, {{t -> 87, a[1] -> 87, o[1] -> 0}}}`

```
(myexpr /. FindInstance[#, Variables[myexpr]]) & /@ (List @@ mycond)
```

> {{{454, 10}}, {{2649237, 173}}}

```
({myexpr /. #, #} &@ FindInstance[#, Variables[myexpr]]) & /@ (List @@ mycond)
```

> `{{{{454, 10}}, {{t -> 3, a[1] -> 3, o[1] -> 5}}},
>   {{{2649237,  173}}, {{t -> 87, a[1] -> 87, o[1] -> 0}}}}`

If you wish you can use third argument of `FindInstance` to generate multiple examples:

```
Grid[(Transpose[{myexpr /. #, #}] & @  FindInstance[#, Variables[myexpr], 3]) & 
 /@ (List @@ mycond), Dividers -> All ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, but I was looking into tabulating all instances in an interval [`Max[boundLow,boundMin],Min[boundHigh,boundMax]`] shared for all variables (variables being in the `Integers`) like in my example. I see `FindInstance` has a domain specification, but I don't see if I can use it to generate all instances where variables are restricted by the given interval (Like in my `Table` example)?

Comment: Accepted the answer as it helped me figure out how to solve the example problem of tabulating solutions (mentioned in my previous comment) via `FindInstance`- I can use what you present here after splitting the conditions beforehand  into intervals so that each contains one solution.

Comment: @Vepir, thank you for the accept.